# Java Mail API route emails without modifying the FROM header

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have 2 email addresses and I want to route (auto forward) all my mails from one email address to the other. This feature on my mail client unfortunately stopped working and I wanted to create a small console application that will check my emails and forward them automatically on every 10 min.

I started developing a console application in Java using Java Mail API, but I have a problem with setting the appropriate FROM header. When I set the original FROM email address and I try to send the email, SMTP throws and exception: `SMTP mail FROM does not match authenticated user name`.

It seams logical because this way I can fake email addresses senders, but I don't want emails coming on the other email like they were sent by me. This is needed for multiple reasons:

1. Easier readability
2. When I want to reply to the email I want to be able to reply to my original sender and not to my self

I have achieved this on my website contact form using PHP, but I dont know how to do this in Java.

---

*I will try to explain the situation in more simple manner.*

I poses 2 emails: `a@a.com` and `b@b.com`

Now email comes from `c@c.com` to `a@a.com`

I want to forward the email from `a@a.com` to `b@b.com`, but when the mail comes to `b@b.com` in the FROM header I want to see that it came from `c@c.com` (NOT from `a@a.com`)

My question is: Is this possible and if it is how can I set the header FROM to be the original sender.

This is my code:

```
public class ForwardMailService {

    public static void forward() {
        String popHost = "pop.a.com";
        String popPort = "110"; // 995 SSL

        String imapHost = "imap.a.com";
        String imapPort = "143"; // 993 SSL

        String smtpHost = "smtp.a.com";
        String smtpPort = "25";

        String user = "USERNAME";
        String password = "PASSWORD";

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
        properties.put("mail.imap.host", imapHost);
        properties.put("mail.imap.port", imapPort);
        properties.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");

        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        try {
            Store store = session.getStore("imap");
            store.connect(imapHost, user, password);

            Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            SearchTerm searchTerm = new SentDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GE, new Date());
            Message[] messages = folder.search(searchTerm);
            if(messages.length != 0) {
                for(Message message : messages) {                    
                    String from = InternetAddress.toString(message.getFrom());
                    String replyTo = InternetAddress.toString(message.getReplyTo());
                    String to = InternetAddress.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
                    String subject = message.getSubject();
                    Date sentDate = message.getSentDate();

                    Message forward = new MimeMessage(session);
                    forward.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("a@a.com));
                    forward.setSubject("Fwd: " + message.getSubject());
                    forward.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                    forward.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(replyTo));

                    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                    messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "message/rfc822");
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                    forward.setContent(multipart);
                    forward.saveChanges();

                    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
                    try {
                        transport.connect(smtpHost, user, password);
                        transport.sendMessage(forward, forward.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
                    } catch(Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        transport.close();
                    }
                }
            }


            folder.close(false);
            store.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on your mail server whether it will let you send mail to b@b.com without it appearing to come from a@a.com.  Most servers will not allow that.

A simpler solution is to read the message from the Inbox of a@a.com and use Folder.appendMessages to append it to the Inbox of b@b.com, instead of using Transport.sendMessage to re-send it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking about doing the same thing. I will try this later today and I will get back to you if it works.